# html5 audio 'mediaplayable' event?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

my app lets user drag songs to add them. I was wondering how can i make sure that the files user dragged are actually music files and are playable? i can use `loadedmetadata` event but how would i know when a file does not get loaded so that i can discard it?

i remember readng about an event that would tell if the file is *playable*. I googled a lot but couldn't find it, maybe my mind is making things up.. so how can i know weather a file is playable? checking file extension is an option but i would like to make it platform independent and different platform plays different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up with was the `progress` event. `canplay` waits for data to be loaded so that some of it can be played, but `progress` shows that the media is available and it is now progressing to download its meta.. If given an invalid file, it throws an `error` event *instead* of `progress` hence facilitates the knowledge of weather the file is a valid and playable media file or not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you ar looking for `canplay` event:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#mediaevents

Comment: ! yes apparently that is it but how can i know if the file cannot be played? will the `error` callback be fired if i try a file that is not a music file?